# MVC view engine alternatives to T4 for compile-time code generation of C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-generation

T4 isn't too bad but it has lots of warts and is beginning to show its age.

Given the advances in MVC view engines in the past 18 months or so (razor, spark, etc) I was wondering whether there have been any successful efforts to use these for rendering of code model views (or other words: code generation).  Ideally it should be possible  to leverage the same engine in both ASP.NET MVC and the code generation environment so that our view engine-centric investments will carry over to the code gen infrastructure, and to minimize the learning curve of devs who would otherwise need to learn T4 as well.

I'm aware of a few of the OSS code gen libraries such as NVelocity, I'm explicitly asking about libraries/frameworks which use ASP.NET MVC compatible view engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor and kin are really just templating engines. But it may be pretty painfull to use it for code generation as you want  a clear way to distinguish generator code from code literals embeedded in the template. You could embedd code literals within the `<text>` tag in Razor, but it seems like you would end up with a lot of noise.

Try [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) out for size:

http://razorengine.codeplex.com/